# jXLS evaluate inner variable

Tags: java, xls, jxls

I tried to evaluate an inner variable like ${messages.${column}} in my first jXLS template without any success.

Could someone help It is even possible? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers
Joska

Answer (score 1):

Any object property graph depth is possible. For example,

```
${bean.bean1.bean2.bean3.bean4.bean5.bean6.bean7.bean8.bean9.beanX.property1}
```

In your case `${messages.${column}}` should be `${message.column}` if I understand your question correctly